# java8 how to create nested lists?

Tags: java, java-8

Learning and playing around with Java8. Trying to create a 2D array.

```
final List<Integer> row = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<List<Integer>> arr2D = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                     .map(i -> arr2D.add(i, row)); // will not compile
```

how do I put the row into the 2D array? and is this the correct way of using Java8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question mentions arrays, but your code has only Lists. If you want to generate a nested List :

```
List<List<Integer>> arr2D = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                     .mapToObj(i -> row)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course with this code all the inner Lists will be identical (i.e. the same instance). If you want each inner List to be a different instance :

```
List<List<Integer>> arr2D = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                     .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Integer>(row))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here, your code is giving me `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Integer> to int` error.

Comment: @Z-1 Oh, My mistake. Since you are mapping from an int to a reference type, change `map` to `mapToObj`.

Comment: just a side question, if I am only using the nested list as a maze (just traversing it, not changing or updating), then having all innner Lists as the same instance is the best approach right?

Comment: @Z-1 If you don't modify the inner List, then it doesn't matter that all the inner Lists are the same instance. However, if you're not modifying them and don't mind that they all refer to the same instance, why do you need a nested List at all? Wouldn't the inner List instance be enough?

Comment: @Z-1: Then you should wrap the inner list via [`unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) before creating the nested list, to make sure, you notice if your assumption, that only read traversals happen, is wrong. And then, you don’t need a stream operation at all, just say `arr2D=Collections.nCopies(3, Collections.unmodifiableList(row));`…

Comment: @eran come to think of it, yes, you're right. Having a nested list just helps me think mentally. But yes, you're right. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Holger Great, I like that. Is there a difference between this `List<Integer> row = Collections.unmodifiableList(IntStream.range(0, 3).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));` and your implementation?

Comment: @Z-1: not for the `arr2D`, but in your variant, `row` also points to the immutable list, which is preferable. You may also inline it if the `row` variable is not needed: `arr2D=Collections.nCopies(3, Collections.unmodifiableList(IntStream.range(0, 3).boxed() .collect(Collectors.toList())));`

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                     .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                                             .mapToObj(j -> j)
                                                             .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Works great! Can you please explain why you used `mapToObj` instead of `boxed` for the inner loop?

Comment: @Z-1 I wasn't aware that `boxed()` method existed. In the current implementation `boxed()`does the same thing: `public final Stream<Integer> boxed() {
        return mapToObj(Integer::valueOf);
    }` ; the only difference is the code from the answer uses autoboxing.

Comment: is that the source code of `boxed`? Can you please share where you got it from?